# iOS: Can the UIImagePickerController Default UI be modified?

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, customizing

I am working with a small camera app for a client and I have now finished all functionality of it. In the standard camera controls i need to modify one thing , the cancel button should say gallery instead. 
But unless i am missing something i will need to remove the overlay by setting `showsCameraControls` to NO and then building my entire overlayView from scratch. 
I have found this solution but I am afraid to go this route due to the warning [in the beginning of the post](http://www.codza.com/custom-uiimagepickercontroller-camera-view).

So is there any valid way of doing simple small modifications to the existing camera overlay control UI or do you have to build it from scratch if you need to change one tiiiiiiny thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, having been in this situation I can safely say you need to build the controls from scratch. You really only have two options: create your own camera overlay, or use the default one.

Now, you *could* use the techniques described in the link you cite, and iterate through the various subviews and modify them 'blind'. The rather large danger with this is every time Apple change the internal structure of the image picker it could potentially break your solution. So I'd definitely stay clear of it.